# how to put "%" in chart pie (chartjs)

Tags: javascript, charts, label, chart.js

I need to put % after the number in the chart:

Like: 100%

[image]

This is the code that i'm using to make the chart, using chart js:

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("pie-chart-one"), {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ['Transmitidas', 'Não Transmitidas'],
        datasets: [{
            data: [@Model.PorcentQtdDeclaracoesStatusTransmitida, @Model.PorcentQtdDeclaracoesStatusNaoTransmitida],
            backgroundColor: backgroudColor,
            borderWidth: 1,
        }]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'bottom',
            fontSize: 10

        },
       responsive:false,
       fontsize: 11,
       layout: {
           padding: {
               left: 0,
               right: 0,
               top: 30,
               bottom: 30
           }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem using a callback and a title inside the tooltip:

```
options: {
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                    var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
                    var total = dataset.data.reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
                        return previousValue + currentValue;
                    });
                    var currentValue = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index];
                    var percentage = Math.floor(((currentValue / total) * 100) + 0.5);
                    return percentage + "%";
                },                    
                title: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                    return data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index];
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

in options definitions...

```
options: {
        tooltips: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'single',
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItems, data) { 
                    return tooltipItems.yLabel + ' %';
                }
            }
        },
 }
```

Comment: It didn't work, just show "%" not all text. Sorry i don't know why it didn't work. Looks right.

Comment: please you can check the version chartjs that you use